# How can you split an edge in 3 or more edges?

Tags: faces, edges

Is there a way to split an edge into more than 2 equal edges? Same for faces I was using another program that had this option and it was quite handy.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: W > Subdivide > Adjust number of cuts

Answer (score 2):

First of all, go to Edit Mode and select the edge you want to split, then click the Subdivide button (step 1 in the picture below) and adjust the number of cuts in the panel that appears below (step 2). Also make sure you don't do anything else before adjusting the number of cuts, or the panel will disappear because Blender doesn't store that kind of information in its history, so even if you do Ctrl+Z the edge will return as it was before subdividing but the panel will not reappear and you'll have to do the procedure again.

[image: subdivide]

Answer (score 0):

First thing that came to mind was ctrl-B and then roll up with the middle mouse button.

Comment: Note that Ctrl+B won't do anything with an edge (Ctrl+Shift+B as well because there won't be anywhere to move beveled vertices)